# C# Client Server Module , Serialization Does not work

Tags: c#, serialization, stream, network-programming, client

Firstly I would like to define the problem. 
 
I am to write communication module between a client and a server.  
 
What does Client do ? 
 
- sends Raport to server ---> sendReport(Raport raport) 
 
- gets specyfic Raport from server --> getReport() method 
 
- gets Info list about available raports   ---->  getRaportsInfo()

Client class http://pastebin.com/344kfcbh

What does Server do ?
 
- gets the requests from client ( based on the first byte in the stream )
 
Server Class  http://pastebin.com/wBwFPRpK

Report Class

```
    namespace OtherClasses
   {
   [Serializable]
   public class Raport
   {
    public int day;
    public int month;
    public int year;

    public Raport(int d, int m, int y)
    {
        day = d;
        month = m;
        year = y;
    }

    public void show()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("DAY=" + day + " MONTH=" + month + "YEAR=" + year);

    }

}
```

}

Somewhere in the Mains

```
 Server s = new Server();
 s.acceptConnection();
 Client c = new Client();
 Raport r1 = new Raport(1, 1, 1);
 c.connect("127.0.0.1");
 c.sendReport(r1);
```

Problem: apparently after reading the first byte from the stream I cannot deserialize. 
 
 I'm getting error "The input stream is not a valid binary format. "
 
 SerializationException   
 How Can i deserialize from my stream after reading the first byte

Comment: Is this Raport class copied into both projects? Or is it in a library (dll) that both projects are referencing?

Comment: Btw - the use of BinaryWriter and a raw stream is confusing and I think incorrect here: you are doing "write 3 on writer", "serialize to stream", "flush writer". Should be "write 3 on writer, "flush writer", "serialize to stream". Or even better: "write 3 to stream, serialize to stream" (lose the writer)

Comment: Additional spot: the 3 you are writing isn't a byte. Yet you read it as though it were.

Comment: As Marc says w.Write((byte)3); and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps include the command in the class? Use different classes to specify the needed data. Something like:

```
public enum RaportType {specific,general};

[Serializable]
public class RaportSpecific
{
    public List<string> Data = new List<string>() { "One", "Two" };
}

[Serializable]
public class Raport
{
    public RaportType RaportType = RaportType.specific;
    public RaportSpecific Test = null;   //new RaportSpecific();
```

..

Server:

```
IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
Raport receivedRaport = (Raport)formatter.Deserialize(n);
switch (receivedRaport.RaportType)
{

    case RaportType.general:
        Debug.WriteLine("You wanted to getRaportsInfo()");
        /// to be implemented
        break;

    case RaportType.specific:
        Debug.WriteLine("I've received your raport");
        receivedRaport.show();
        break;
```